# General URL routing

Tags: joomla

I recently took over a personal Joomla project after another dev abandoned it and I'm having trouble getting a hold of some fundamentals here.
I've worked in several other web development frameworks, but Joomla paradigm seems very different and the documentation is presented in a vastly different way.

The previous dev has the root URL (site.com) and site.com/index.php serving up the article 'home',
and had all other URLs (site.com/gallery, site.com/contact) serving up the article 'stuff'. 
I just can't figure out where it is determined that article X will be served for URL Y.
I believe the project is Joomla 1.6.
A straight-up answer or a good article link will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the rewritten URL go to the same screen (Menus | Main Menu | Menu Item) and change the "Alias" field to the new required value.

If you need to see the original URL before it is re-rewritten go to the same place and look at the "Link" field. The "Menu Item Type" will tell you what type of object the menu is pointing to.

Some of this does depend on what rewriting you are using. The above assumes it's just the Joomla default. Other tools like joomsef can override this stuff.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. It's little details like this that seem to get lost in the huge articles full of information I already know